# Cookie only displayed on refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have some trouble understanding this one so here it is.

**I'm trying to set a cookie and display the value on the page using ASP.NET + C#.**

here's my code:

```
protected void lbChangeToSmall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cookies["fontSize"].Value = "small";
        }
```

and

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lbChangeToSmall" Text="A" CssClass="txt-sm" OnClick="lbChangeToSmall_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And finally

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Write( Request.Cookies["fontSize"].Value);
            }

        }
```

When I click on the button, nothing is displayed on the page, but the cookie is actually set. If I refresh the page, the cookie displays.

So it seems that the cookie is set correctly but the application is not able to read it right away.

I tried to get rid of the if(postBack):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Response.Write( Request.Cookies["virgilFontSize"].Value);
        }
```

but it didn't change a thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lblChangeToSmall_Click` event is fired after the `Page_Load` event.  Therefore the cookie write won't be available on the Request until the subsequent postback.

It will be avaialable on the client immediately though.

Comment: Oh, I thought that it would call the method, then refresh the page, calling page_load... Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Set the font size on the client with Javascript.  Or do another redirect to the page.  Or look at what the page_load actually needs to do with the cookie and do that from the click event as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How can I do another redirect to the page? These buttons are on the master page, so I don't know to what page I wan't to redirect. I don't think i can redirect to "". Redirecting to "?" sends me to url.com/page.aspx/? which break.

Answer (score 0):

The first time, the *request* has no cookies (yet); it will only have them the second time around, after the *response* has set them. So your code has to deal with the possibility that `Request.Cookies` just may not *have* a `"fontSize"` entry, and provide the proper default when that is the case.  For example:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("fontSize");
// Check if cookie exists in the current request.
if (cookie == null)
{
   Response.Write( "Defaulting to 'small'.");
}
else
{
   Response.Write( Request.Cookies["fontSize"].Value);
)
```

Comment: it's part of the HTTP standard -- you can't realistically change it. Editing my answer to show how to _deal_ with it...