# PHP cookie has a one refresh delay

Tags: php, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cookie only displayed on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983795/cookie-only-displayed-on-refresh)

I'm trying to set a basic PHP cookie that will remember which color theme a uses. When I test it out however, there is a one-refresh lag between the setting and the displaying of the color theme.

To clarify: I have a select-form that will allow users to choose colors. Then, there is an apply button. Once that apply button is chosen, the page should automatically set the cookie and show the color. However, when the apply button is pressed, only the cookie is set and the theme is not shown until the user hits the refresh button. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
$help = $_POST["theme"];
    $color = "#" . $help;
    setcookie("TestCookie", $color, time()+60*60*24);
    $recolor = $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
    echo '<style type="text/css"> body { background: '.$recolor.' } </style>';
```

where $_POST["theme"] is the select-form name. Thanks a lot! this: [Cookie only displayed on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983795/cookie-only-displayed-on-refresh) is what I'm talking about, but with PHP, not C#

Edit: Thanks for all the replies! I managed to work around this by setting the background color to whatever the user picked while setting the cookie at the same time. So when the user initially picks the color, it isn't the cookie setting the background. It's another function. It feels kinda cheap, but it works!

Comment: @PeeHaa he wrote that it is a possible duplicate but with C# and not PHP :)

Comment: And it's not a possible duplicate. He want's to know a workaround on how to set the theme when he hits the apply button.

Comment: One dead simple workaround: set the cookie with setcookie and set the superglobal $_COOKIE at the same time; that way it'll be available in the same request.

Comment: Yeah that's what trying to do. I think I know of a way to do it however.

Comment: It's really simple, if you do setcookie("TestCookie", $color, time()+60*60*24); you can do $_COOKIE['TestCookie'] = $color; in the line immediately after and it will work as you would expect.

Answer (score 5):

The $_COOKIE superglobal has the cookies available at the time you requested that page, that is why you will never see the values you just saved

On the man page here http://php.net/set_cookie you can see:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page
>   load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

Comment: But I know of a website that can do the exact same thing, which is set color to "blue" if the user chose blue, and set the cookie at the same time, all made using PHP

Comment: they might set the cookie via javascript.. or if you are sure that it is php-only they might add the value in the $_COOKIE superglobal at the time the cookie is set also

Answer (score 4):

That's because setcookie is not modifiing $_COOKIE variable. You must use `setcookie` and at the same time set relevant value in $_COOKIE

Answer (score 2):

I expect it's because you're setting the cookie, and then checking for the value on the next line of code - you won't be able to see it yet, because at that point, the client will have sent the request for the page, which won't yet include the cookie.

You could try using a `$_SESSION` instead - just swap your references to `$_COOKIE` to $_SESSION throughout.

Failing that, try explicitly checking to see if the form has just been submitted, and and setting the style based on the values they've just submitted.

Comment: what about the set cookie() function?

Comment: To set it: `$_SESSION["color"] = $color;` and to access it: `$recolor = $_SESSION["TestCookie"];`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to **ShogunArts.de**'s sulotion,
when you `setcookie()`, this "command" has to be send to the browser first via HTTP Headers. Same applies when you try to access the super global `$_COOKIE` it won't contain the cookie value unless returned by the browser also via HTTP headers.

Here's what happens:

1. Page requested (the browser doesn't have the cookie yet)
2. `setcookie()` called.
3. Script finished executing and now it will RESPOND to the browser telling it to set the cookie.
4. When the page is accessed again now that the browser has the cookie it will send it along with the request.
5. Now that PHP has received a request with a cookie it sets the `$_COOKIE` super global and now you can access it with your script.

Answer (score 1):

Ask if the cookie is set:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["TestCookie"])) $recolor = $_COOKIE["TestCookie"]; 
else $recolor = $color;
```

Comment: +1, I quite like it. I don't know why it was downvoted. Although you didn't explain anything, but I don't think this answer `is not useful`

Comment: Maybe cause it got an error in it before (forgot "] at the end of the key, cause of copy & paste issue). But it's exactly what the OP want. Quote: "However, when the apply button is pressed, only the cookie is set and the theme is not shown until the user hits the refresh button. Any ideas on how to solve this?" So he want's to set the theme on click and don't want to know WHY the cookie is only available after refresh.

Comment: What I mean by explaining is that you explain YOUR answer, you just dumped a code. However I still think is answer is very useful as you're the only one who actually offered a solution. I'll reference it in my answer.