# Change Cookie w/ Ajax: Strange Delay

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm coding a fairly simple function here. I'm using cookies to limit users to five votes per day (not perfect, in fact pretty easy to get around, but the client insisted, no user accounts, so this was the next best option).

So, I'm using an Ajax call in Javascript to change the Cookie on the fly - every time a user clicks a 'Vote Up' button, Ajax talks to a PHP file that reduces the cookie value by one.

But there's an odd delay happening. I've told Ajax to console.log the cookie value (echoed out in the PHP file), and I'm getting a delay of one value when in the log. The cookie STARTS at 5, so when I click 'vote' once, I should get a console.log of '4', because the value was decreased by 1 and then logged. Instead, I get '5'. The NEXT time, which should be '3', I get '4', and so on.

My code is posted below. I'm honestly not sure what to do here - I've thought through the code logically, and unless my head just isn't working, I can't see why this wouldn't be working.

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "includes/user_vote.php",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //log the error if the ajax function fails
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },

    complete: function(data){

    }
});
```

user_vote.php:

```
if($_COOKIE['votes_left'] <= 0){
    $newVal = 0;
} else {
    $newVal = $_COOKIE['votes_left'] - 1;
}

setcookie('votes_left', $newVal, strtotime('today 23:59'), "/");
echo $_COOKIE['votes_left'];
```

There's a little more PHP, not directly related to this, but posting it here anyway. It runs on index.php to set the cookie if it isn't already set.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['votes_left'])){

    $votes = 5;
    $time = date('h:i:s');

    setcookie('votes_left', $votes, strtotime('today 23:59'), "/");
    setcookie('set_time', $time, strtotime('today 23:59'), "/");

}
```

Comment: Is that **all** your `PHP` code? If there is more please add it.

Comment: Hey - it's all the PHP code in user_vote.php. Why, should there be more?

Comment: The only other PHP is initially setting the cookie if it isn't already set, right in index.php. Added it to the main post.

Comment: Ugh. That's a pretty weak problem with cookies. I suppose I could do a double-AJAX call, once to set it, again to query it.

Comment: or you could check for the value -1 when you perform your check. Kinda dirty but its a quick fix and less requests to the server.

Comment: No need to do two calls. Just `echo $newVal` instead of `echo $_COOKIE['votes_left']`.

Comment: Those are both true - I try to avoid using what the value SHOULD be, I prefer to echo what the value truly IS. But it might be slightly ridiculous in this case to make that many multiple calls to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the post I will link below mentions, the Cookie Super Global will only show the value at the time that you requested the page, therefor you will never see the value you just set it to. Check this post for more details

[PHP cookie has a one refresh delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471674/php-cookie-has-a-one-refresh-delay)

Comment: If your answer is basically the same as what was said in the post you link to, you should just flag this as a duplicate rather than posting a link-only answer.

Comment: ok, thanks. Doesnt look like link only to me, but hey.